# react native, how to detect the actual scrolling action end?

Tags: react-native, scroll

I have a situation that requires me to detect when a scrolling view (either a ScrollView, FlatList or other component) has ended the scroll action entirely - that is, both the user stopped scrolling, and any momentum scrolling has ended.

The problem is that there is no event that is triggered when the scrolling has ended entirely, instead, the two event callbacks `onScrollEnd` and `onMomentumScrollEnd` are provided - neither of which is guaranteed to be called.

Calling any `scrollTo*` methods on the instances of the scrolling components will not trigger any of these events.

User scrolling will always trigger `onScrollEnd`, but it might not trigger `onMomentumScrollEnd` if momentum is disabled, or if they do not make a momentum scroll (such as when lifting the finger without making any more scroll motion).

Using the same function to do the same action on both `onScrollEnd` and `onMomentumScrollEnd` events, creates weird visual artifacts due to components re-rendering and animating on the screen.

Using a setTimeout() to wait x time to consider the scroll ended does not help because, if momentum is very low, the scroll might take several seconds to actually end - but it might take only a few hundred milliseconds in other cases.

Detecting the scroll offset of childs does not work because I am not binding the end of the scroll with the actual start/end of the scroll boundaries.

Does anyone know how can I detect the actual end of a scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i had the same issue so what i did is to detect is there is Momentum
i did it by listen to onMomentumScrollBegin and if it fire so isMomentum was true and then onScrollEndDrag use setTimeout of 0 and check if isMomentum was false

```
 onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => onScrollMomentumEnd({ event })}
        onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
          isHasMomentum = true;
        }}
        onScrollEndDrag={(event: any) => {
          const nativeEvent = event.nativeEvent;
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (!isHasMomentum) {
              onScrollMomentumEnd({ nativeEvent });
            }
          }, 0);
        }}
```

Comment: Thank you for ofering this solution. As far as I can tell however, it suffers the same issues as I described in my post, the scroll end events are not triggered consistently when the user interacts (e.g. a drag event instead of a flick scroll that triggers momentum). In the end, I personally ended up not triggering my code on a scroll end event, and instead, I am using an `Animated.ScrollView / Value / View` approach.